# Проблемы с SQL на php

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

### При запросе sql выдает такое:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in путь/trolleybus.php on line 132
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in путь/trolleybus.php on line 134

С верхним неактивным запросом работает, а с новым который чуть ниже нет:

```
<?php
                        
                        $str= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'f0486085_base');


                        //ЭТОТ ЗАПРОС РАБОТАЕТ:$select= mysqli_query($str, "SELECT `trolleybus`.* FROM `trolleybus`");

                        $select= mysqli_query($sql = "SELECT `trolleybus`.*, `sitys`.`sity`\n . FROM `sitys`, `trolleybus`\n . ORDER BY `trolleybus`.`brand` DESC\n . LIMIT 0, 30 ");

                        while ($r= mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
                    
                         echo '<tr>'.'<td>'.'<b>'.$r['id'] .'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['brand'] .'</b>'.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['name'] .'</b>'.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['year'] .'</b>'.'<b>г.</b>'.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['factory'] .'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['country'] .'</b>'.'</td>';
                         echo '<td>'.'<b>'.$r['sity'] .'</b>'.'</td>';
                         if ($r['current'] < '1'){ 
                            echo '<td>'.'<b>&#10008</b>'.'</td>'.'</tr>';
                            }
                         else{
                            echo '<td>'.'<b>&#10003;</b>'.'</td>'.'</tr>';
                            }
                        }
                        mysqli_close($str);

                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо **$str** переменной написал **$sql** надо быть внимательнее. phpmyadmin делает чуть другой код php из sql запроса.